# jquery-match-height not working on first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using [jquery-match-height](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) plugin on my website.

I can't understand why the plugin does not work on the first row. It seems like the plugin is trying to output the style height, but it is empty on the first row. Second row is working fine.

**html**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row article-box-list">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 article-box">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/768x410/000/fff" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>

                <div class="well well-white">
                    <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</a></h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. <a href="#">More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 article-box">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/768x853/000/fff" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>

                <div class="well well-white">
                    <h4><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. <a href="#">More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /first-row-->




    <div class="row article-box-list">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 article-box">
            <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/768x585/000/fff" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>

            <div class="well well-white">
                <h4><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. <a href="#">More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 article-box">
            <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/768x585/000/fff" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>

            <div class="well well-white">
                <h4><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></h4>
                <p class="ingress">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.<a href="#">More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 article-box">
            <a href="#" class="img-link"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/768x585/000/fff" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>

            <div class="well well-white">
                <h4><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</a></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer. <a href="#">More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div><!--/ last-row-->


</div>
```

**js**

```
$(function() {
    $('.article-box .well').matchHeight();
});
```

<strike>My bootply: [view](http://www.bootply.com/yiUUGAlgZ5)</strike> (does not seem to be working atm)

My jsfiddle: [view](http://jsfiddle.net/9ru53a28/)

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Observation : change h2 tag in first row to h4 then it stated working for high resolutions screens above 1200 px, if I remove anchor tags, its working all the time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Samus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253638/1852838) is actually quite close but given that what you want is to:

- match the height's of the `.article-box .well` elements within each row
- have differing matched heights for each row

And the fact that the plugin simply makes the promise:

> matchHeight makes the height of all selected elements exactly equal

The solution is to select the elements within each row individually and apply the plugin to each collection separately like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('.row').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem)
            .find('.article-box .well')   // Only children of this row
            .matchHeight({byRow: false}); // Row detection gets confused so disable it
    });
});
```

You can see this at work in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9ru53a28/20/) update to your jsFiddle. You'll notice the wells in the first row and the wells in the second one are a different height but the same within each row if you inspect them with your browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 7):

Default option is by row - https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height#options

```
$('.article-box .well').matchHeight({ 
     byRow: 0
});
```

There you go. :)

Comment: Yes, and of course I want by row! If I have a box on the fourth row with a large height, I only want the fourth row boxes to match that height, the other rows should match the highest box in their own row.

Comment: @Garreth00 does it not do that?

Comment: If I turn of byRow (0/False) all the boxes on the page get the same size, not only the ones in the same row.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Bootstrap equal-column-height CSS-only fix from Minimit instead:

http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

You will also need this CSS on the `wells` for them to fill the now-equal height columns:

```
.well {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are applying `matchHeight()` on `.article-box .well` which does not have any siblings.

It should be

```
$(function() {
   $('.article-box').matchHeight();
});
```

Appply some background color to `article-box` to see result.

Answer (score 1):

Scrap the plugin. Do it manually:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ru53a28/16/

```
$(function() {
    $('.row').each(function() {
        var intHeight = 0;
        $(this).find('.well').each(function() {
            if ($(this).outerHeight() > intHeight) {
               intHeight = $(this).outerHeight()
            }
        });
        $(this).find('.well').each(function() {
            $(this).outerHeight(intHeight)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where matchHeight seemed to be not working, however after debugging I realised that the very first element under the DIV that I was targeting had a negative margin top value. **jQuery matchHeight has issues with negative margin values**.

Just posting it here so that it could be of help to somebody who might be using negative margin values with matchHeight.